# Add ports to existing Simulink S-Function

Tags: simulink

Is it possible to add a port to an already existing Simulink function? It has already been created with no in/out ports, and I can't find anything in the GUI or documentation about adding ports except when you run the add_block function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the source code?  Is it a mex file or an M file?  If you do have the source code, see the [S-function documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bsd99w_-1.html) for information on setting the number of ports.  If you don't have the source code, you can't add any ports.

Comment: I actually got it to add ports if I edit the .mdl file by hand before running open_system(model), and I can use the GUI to connect lines to each port But the second I use Matlab/Simulink to edit the S-Function, the ports disappear and the lines become disconnected.

This doesn't happen with our generic Simulink model we test with, only this particular one a customer gave us. I'm thinking it's some setting on Simulink's end but I don't know enough about either piece of software to know what it would be.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it pointed me in the direction to check the source for the S-Function. Turns out there was a bug in the S-Function C code that would default the ports to 1 and 1 if a certain configuration file was not present.